# Unable to zipalign the android apk manually

Tags: android, cordova, zipalign

I used the command like:

```
D:\>C:\Users\SCS\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\zipalign -v 4 D:\AppBuilds\ProAppPlayStore_11082016\appcodeByAbhijit\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\original.apk D:\AppBuilds\ProAppPlayStore_11082016\appcodeByAbhijit\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\result.apk
```

but it is resulting this :

```
Usage: zipalign [-f] [-p] [-v] [-z] <align> infile.zip outfile.zip
       zipalign -c [-v] <align> infile.zip

<align>: alignment in bytes, e.g. '4' provides 32-bit alignment
-c: check alignment only (does not modify file)
-f: overwrite existing outfile.zip
-p: page align stored shared object files
-v: verbose output
-z: recompress using Zopfli
```

Please anyone suggest me how to use zipalign

Comment: Can you try with the 19.0.0 built tools?

Comment: Hey i got the solution before using the above command set the path for zipalign in "Advanced ->environment veriables"

Comment: Is your apk corrupt?